# Single Jordan Block

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Guys would you help me about what does "single jordan block" mean? Does single represent geometric multiplicity or algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: Neither. Saying there's a single Jordan block just says there's exactly one block.

Answer (score 0):

A [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is a matrix of the form
$$
J = \pmatrix{\lambda & 1\\&\lambda&1\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&\lambda&1\\&&&&\lambda}.
$$